# Token inesperado de TypeScript, se esperaba un constructor, método, descriptor de acceso o propiedad

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Tengo un error al implementar la interfaz OnInit, que estoy haciendo mal?
Lo raro es que e estado aciendo basicamente lo mismo pero en este componente me sale el error :error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HeroesService } from '../../servicios/heroes.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-buscar-heroe',
  templateUrl: './buscar-heroe.component.html'
})
export class BuscarHeroeComponent implements OnInit {

  let arreglo:any[] = [];

  constructor( _heroesService:HeroesService, activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute,  router:Router){ 

  }

  ngOnInit(){       
    this.buscar();
  }

  buscar(){
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
        console.log('params',params);
        this.arreglo = this._heroesService.buscarHeroes(params['termino']);
      });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Estás definiendo un atributo de la clase como si fuera una variable local, elimina `let` en la declaración de `arreglo` y todo funcionará